# Quartz.Net ZeroSizeThreadPool high CPU usage

Tags: quartz.net

For some reason when I configure and start the ZeroSizeThreadPool Quartz.net scheduler as below, the CPU usage is very high making the computer unresponsive... Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening and how to fix the problem? TIA.

```
        var properties = new NameValueCollection();
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "MyScheduler";
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "instance_myscheduler";
        properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.ZeroSizeThreadPool, Quartz";            
        properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.clustered"] = "false";
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Server=(local);Database=mydb;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;";
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";
        schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        Scheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        Scheduler.Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to start the ZeroSizeThreadPool scheduler. It can schedule the jobs without being started so just don't call Start() method and the CPU usage will not spike.

Comment: So you are saying don't "Scheduler.Start();"?, but I thought Start was needed to begin the IJob Execution.

Comment: @Demodave ZeroThreadScheduler is not executing any jobs, it's only used to create new triggers...